# Meta Description has HTML entities, will Google show the real character or the entity code in SERP?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description

Will Google's SERP show the ampersand (&) or the ampersand HTML entity `&amp;` in its snippet? Here is my description meta tag:

`<meta content="Questions &amp; Answers" name="description"/>`

Answer (score 4):

Unless something is wrong on Google’s side, they’ll display `&amp;` as `&` if used in HTML.

(Note that in HTML5 you don’t have to encode the ampersand in your specific example, [because it’s not ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586767/1591669).)